# Date.parse strange format accepted

Tags: javascript

Chrome Canary Console:

```
new Date(Date.parse("%4"))
Sun Apr 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

No comprendo amigos, elucidation welcome.

Comment: It's the same as `Date.parse("4")`, and note that it returns the fourth month.

Comment: Ok, so it thinks % is wildcard, I suppose, thanks, also you can answer for points. lol, nevermind, you're obviously a SO point monopoly man.